# How to configure win10 to use ODBC drivers?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-10, odbc

I have a software developed in c# that must connect to SQL Server database, I must install it on a virtual machine not configured. I'm experiencing problems with performing a simple query.

Software is installed in other customers servers, so I'm quite sure about the correctness of the code. The problem could be, in my opinion, the configuration of the software or the configuration of ODBC in windows.

I'm using the following connection string:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=<serverName>;Database=<dbName>;Uid=<user>;Pwd=<password>;
```

and I configured the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM [dbName].[dbo].[TABLE]
```

In ODBC side:

- I installed SSMS to check the connection is good, and it connects to
  the DB correctly.
- Drivers in the VM are (from settings>data source):

  - SQL Server Native Client 11.0
  - SQL Server ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

nothing under User DSN and System DSN.

Can you help me to troubleshoot this?
Thanks

Comment: *I'm experiencing problems with performing a simple query.*
Is there some exception? Empty results? Could you elaborate what kinds of problems?

Comment: You don't need to configure a DSN since your connection string specifies the driver. If the driver is installed properly, you will see it under the Drivers tab in ODBC Administrator (odbcad32.exe). Also, for SQL Server access from .NET, it would be better to use `SqlClient` as that will perform better for large datasets and avoids the dependency.

Comment: If you have a working system then configure the ODBC driver like Dan says with same setting that are on the working machine.  The driver is in the c:\Program Files folder and you may needed a different version of the driver in the ODBC setup.

Comment: No exceptions, the behavior is similar to an empty result but I think that this isn't the issue, because I see data from SSMS, could be an error in the query?

Comment: Drivers I listed are in the ODBC Administrator, so I suppose are correctly installed, in fact Sql Server management studio works and allow me to read data in the tables. What do you mean saying to use SqlClient?

Comment: SQL Server Management studio doesn't use ODBC, so that fact you can connect via that only proves that SQL is running, it's not relevant to your code issue directly. What is meant by "using SqlClient" is using the `System.Data.SqlClient` library in the .NET code to connect to SQL Server...this will require a [slightly different connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/), but will use the native SQL client library directly to connect to the database, without any requirement for ODBC configuration.

Comment: Accessing MS SQL Databases within C# doesn't require ODBC and I can't see any benefit of caring about it. DataSets or EntityFramework normally use sqlclient or some other driver directly and provide more performant DB access.

If you are using SQL Express, then the network stack may not be configured, meaning accessing the Databases over the network would fail. Maybe this is where your problems may hide.

Comment: It's possible that ODBC isn't the better way to connect SQL Server in terms of performance, but in this case I'm not developing the code but only installing an application developed in the past two years and I can't modify the code now.
The usage of ODBC a choice to be database independant. This application can connect SQL Server, PostgreSQL, mySQL and so on.

Comment: You could ask if the application uses a hard-coded `OdbcConnection`, or if it uses the generic ADO.NET `DbConnection` and `DbProviderFactory`. In the latter case, ODBC is just one of the options to connect; it is still possible to use the native `SqlConnection` by correctly configuring the connection string. For almost no databases supported by ADO.NET is it the case that ODBC is the best option (and this is certainly true for SQL Server); if a native ADO.NET provider is available (and that's the case for all the databases you mentioned) it should be preferred.